# Screen: Cannot exec '/path/to/file': Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, screen

Simply said, I can't execute any file or directory with screen.
The error 'Cannot exec '/path/to/file': permission denied.' occurs every time.

I'm logged in with root, and should have all permissions needed, but it still fails to execute any file.

I'm trying to screen a .js file. (The .js file works fine without screen, and isn't supposed to shut-down/return anything at all.)

Comment: sudo chmod +x /path/to/file

Comment: Seems to work, but when I use screen after that it just terminates immediately.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Right, so I'm trying to screen a .js file, as I want it to be accesable from outside one terminal ETC. (The .js file works fine without screen, and isn't supposed to shut-down/return anything at all.)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce using an sh file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Android Dev said in comments, you must set execution properties for your file, by chmod +x path-to-file or by chmod 777 path-to-file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Update the permissions of the file with chmod:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x path/to/file.sh
   ```
2. For `screen` to execute the file and stay open, you must specify to run it with `sh`:

   ```
   screen -S nameOfSession sh /path/to/file.sh
   ```